# PFQueryTableViewController jump on fetch

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

**Edit 1**

To be clear, [self loadObjects] is not my method it is a method on the PFQueryTableViewController class supplied by parse to pull in new data.

I suspect this might be being caused by the table drawing code, as the tablecellview is configured to be auto-adjust it's height.

Here is the table drawing code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                    object:(PFObject *)object
{
//Setup estimated heights and auto row height

self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;


//Give the cell a static identifier

static NSString *cellIdentifier;

socialPost* post = object;


//Check to see what sort of cell we should be creating, text, image or video

if (object[@"hasImage"] != nil) {

    cellIdentifier = @"posts_with_image";

} else {

    cellIdentifier = @"posts_no_image";
}

//Create cell if needed

hashtagLiveCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[hashtagLiveCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell to show our imformation, loading video and images if needed


cell.postTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",object[@"userName"]];
cell.postText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                             object[@"text"]];


[cell.userImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post.userImageURL]];
[cell.postImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post.imageURL]];

//Set ID's on the custom buttons so we know what object to work with when a button is pressed

cell.approveButtonOutlet.stringID = object.objectId;

[cell.approveButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(approvePostCallback:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

cell.deletButtonOutlet.stringID = object.objectId;

[cell.deletButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(deletePostCallback:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;
}
```

**Original**

I have a PFQueryTableViewController that i am loading with object from parse.

I have a scheduled task set to run every 20 seconds that calls:

```
[self loadObjects]
```

To fetch any new objects, or any changed to objects that have happened.

That all works fine, however if i am scrolled halfway down the tableview when the loadObjects is called the page jumps back to the top. Even if there are no new or changed data available.

Is there an easy way around this, before i start looking into hacky ways to catch the reload and force the table to stay where it is.

Thanks

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `loadObjects` you load the objects from start. And there for you get the first results again.

Try to change `[self loadObjects];` to `[self.tableView reloadData];`.

Comment: Hi Dridia, thanks for the reply. To be clear, the table is of class PFQueryTableViewController and calling [self loadobject] initiates a fetch of any updated objects from the parse servers, as well as updating the tableview, so i'm not sure that calling [self.tableview reloadData] would have the same effect as it would just be telling the tableview to reload the existing data?

Comment: When i call `[self loadObjects]` the page doesn't jump back up to the top. Can you add a bit more code?

Comment: Actually you are correct, it doesn't jump to the top, it just changes position somewhat arbitrarily. I will update the question with the custom row drawing code to see if that helps. I think what i will do in the interim is change the class of the tableview back to a standard UITableView and attach it to an NSMutableArray, i can then fetch the object into a separate array, do a comparison and only update the tables array of there are changes. It should at least minimise the jumping to when there is new data rather than on every fetch.